# Make JFrame GUI wait and then continue after a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I have a gui class MyGUIClass that extends JFrame. I would like to accomplish following in java. I looked into EventQueue, but somehow could not get things right. I am not even sure if this is the correct approach.

In the main, I would like following sequence of events:

-> start JFrame

-> Keep JFrame active and wait until play button is pressed. when button pressed,

-> execute rest of the code in main, but keep gui alive to receive commands from JFrame.

```
            try {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       new MyGUIClass().setVisible(true);
                   }
               });
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Portion to execute only after request from GUI");
            }
```

But the above trial is not working and the println prints while gui is running without any commend from GUI.

Comment: Please post your runnable example, so we can run it and see what's wrong. Also you should read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Thank you for the comment. Runnable is defined in above code. Do you want me to post MyGUIClass() ?

Comment: I want to see a **short** (about 50 lines of code) compilable and runnable example or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Seems you need a modal `JDialog` rather than a frame. The code after `dialog.setVisible(true)` will not proceed until it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to provide a listener to the button on click of which you want to execute some code.

But if you want to put the code which you want to execute in **main**. You will need some anonymous class containing code or lambda etc.

I will show here how you can achieve what you want

```
class MyGUIClass extends JFrame {
    ...
    // I am using Runnable to contain code you want to execute.
    // You can use Function or any class/interface you want
    Runnable codeToExecute;
    MyGUIClass(Runnable codeToExecute){
        this.codeToExecute = codeToExecute;
        ...
    }

    ...
    void yourGUImethod(){
        ...
        JButton btn = new JButton(new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                codeToExecute.run();    // execute code on button press
            }
        });
        yourPanel.add(btn);             // Add this button to your panel
       ...
    }
```

Now you can provide executing code from main

```
Runnable codeToExecute = () -> {     // Using lambda
    System.out.println("Portion to execute only after request from GUI");
}

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new MyGUIClass(codeToExecute).setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am not even sure if this is the correct approach.

Well you haven't stated if this is the main window or a child window.

If this is a "child window" and you are prompting for information from the main window, then you should be using a modal JDialog for the child window.

If this is the "main window" then no it isn't the correct approach.

GUI's are event driven. This means you write code to respond to events.

So, when the frame is created you create all the components and add them to the frame.

For the "Play" button you need to add an ActionListener to the button. So when the button is pressed you invoke the code related to the play action.

Then the GUI will just sit there waiting for more events to be generated by the user.

Comment: Its a main window. Thank you for the comment.